# Countdown timer to Countup

Tags: javascript, timer, countdown

Hello guys i have this countdown script but i want it to countup and instead of updating a div span, update the value of a progress bar.

**HTML**

```
<progress value="**UPDATE THIS**" max="780"></progress>
```

**SCRIPT**

```
var sec = $('#update span').text(), secInit = sec;
        var timer = setInterval(function() {
            $('#update span').text(--sec);
            if (sec == 0) {
                sec = secInit;
                $.ajax({
                    url: "{{ url('/user/update') }}",
                    type: "GET",
                    data: { 'id' : {{ Auth::user()->id }} }
                });
            }
        }, 1000);
```

Any idea?

Thanks,
Tiago

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give the progress bar an ID such as

```
<progress id="progress-bar" value="**UPDATE THIS**" max="780"></progress>
```

and use some javascript to change the value each second, eg.

```
var timer = setInterval(function() {
            var progbar = document.getElementById("progress-bar");
            progbar.value = progbar.value < 780 ? +progbar.value + 1 : 0;
        }, 1000);
```

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzn68wmk/2/)

Comment: *progbar.value* will be a string, so `+progbar.value + 1`. ;-)

Comment: With a max range of 780, 1 second is really slow for this demo. Try 10ms. Then it's easy to see that it counts up. Otherwise, we'd have to wait 13 minutes to see the demo reach 100%.

Comment: Btw, the counter is flawed. It ends up at 781, not 780. Take the = sign out of the ternary check. It should be progbar.value < 780, if you're going to do a +1 right after that. See: <progress id="progress-bar" value="781" max="780"></progress>

Comment: @Clomp thanks, its 780 max and 1 second intervals due to the values in the question though :)

Comment: @IllogicalArgumentException hey guys, it works but it doesnt refresh the bar, i need when it reaches the 780 resets and starts again.. like it does in the countdown

Comment: @TiagoF added a JSFiddle, works fine on there, keep in mind that like noted in your question, it is updating 1/780 each second so will take a long time to fill up (13mins)

Comment: @IllogicalArgumentException i know, but when it reaches the end it doesnt restart, it ended with the full progress bar.. i want to loop it..

Comment: @IllogicalArgumentException Thanks mate :D It works! :) however its odd, cuz i have the countdown and countup for the progress bar, however the countdown working well, but the count up doesnt work the same way, its like 2s behind the countdown :/

Comment: @TiagoF Hard to say without seeing the full code, but you could try something like using the sec global for both counters and setting the progress bar value as the inverse, ie. `progbar.value = 780 - sec`